# Android : What is the difference between converting Bitmap to byte array and Bitmap.compress?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am uploading an image (JPEG) from android phone to server. I tried these two methods - 
 
Method 1 :

```
int bytes=bitmap.getByteCount();
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
        byte[] byteArray = byteBuffer.array();
        outputStream.write(byteArray, 0, bytes-1);
```

Method 2 :

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
```

In method1, I am converting the bitmap to bytearray and writing it to stream. In method 2 I have called the compress function BUT given the quality as `100` (which means no loss I guess).
I expected both to give the same result. BUT the results are very different. In the server the following happened - 
**Method 1 (the uploaded file in server)** : 
A file of size **3.8MB** was uploaded to the server. The uploaded file is unrecognizable. Does not open with any image viewer.
**Method 2 (the uploaded file in server)**
A JPEG file of **415KB** was uploaded to the server. The uploaded file was in JPEG format.
What is the difference between the two methods. How did the size differ so much even though I gave the compression quality as 100? Also why was the file not recognizable by any image viewer in method 1?

Answer (score 2):

> I expected both to give the same result.

I have no idea why.

> What is the difference between the two methods.

The second approach creates a JPEG file. The first one does not. The first one merely makes a copy of the bytes that form the decoded image to the supplied buffer. It does not do so in any particular file format, let alone JPEG.

> How did the size differ so much even though I gave the compression quality as 100?

Because the first approach applies no compression. 100 for JPEG quality does not mean "not compressed".

> Also why was the file not recognizable by any image viewer in method 1?

Because the bytes copied to the buffer are not being written in any particular file format, and certainly not JPEG. That buffer is not designed to be written to disk. Rather, that buffer is designed to be used only to re-create the bitmap later on (e.g., for a bitmap passed over IPC).

Comment: Okay. But the size of the image on disk is 600KB. Then why is method 1 uploading an image of size 3.8MB?

Comment: @Ashwin: Because the image on disk is compressed (PNG, JPEG, etc.), and a `Bitmap` is not compressed.

Comment: So all these formats - PNG, JPEG etc are all methods of compressing the data so that they take less space on disk/less data can be transferred over network? If that is true, then the size of an image being displayed in memory (RAM) is always way higher right?

Comment: @Ashwin: "the size of an image being displayed in memory (RAM) is always way higher?" -- yes.